# can't merge a union all view

Tags: sql, oracle, derived-table, inline-view

I know Oracle RDMS can't merge a view that has a set operator in it. I want to know why is that.

For example, this:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM
 (
  SELECT a.a1    A,
        a.a2    B
   FROM tab_a a
UNION ALL
  SELECT b.b1    A,
         b.b2    B
    FROM tab_b b
)     u,
tab_p p
WHERE p.a = u.a
```

could be transformed into this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (
  SELECT a.a1    A,
         a.a2    B
    FROM tab_a a,
         tab_p p
   WHERE p.a = a.a1
UNION ALL
  SELECT b.b1    A,
         b.b2    B
    FROM tab_b b,
         tab_p p
   WHERE p.a = b.b1
)
```

These two queries are equivalent, right?
[edited]

Comment: What does it mean to "merge a view"?

Comment: @Gabe: It's a transformation that Oracle does to optimize queries. Shown here: http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2007/03/08/transformation-and-optimisation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transformation you describe in your edited question appears valid to me.

There are many many many different query transformations that the Oracle optimizer *could in theory* perform, but in practice this is limited to those transformations that the Oracle team have *actually bothered to implement*.

Each transformation, if added, would require a significant investment in coding and testing, and would only be done if sufficient demand was detected in the paying market.

So, it's not that it "can't", necessarily; it just doesn't, yet.

Answer (score 3):

The queries will produce the same resultset, but the execution plan is likely to be different.  I would expect the first query to be more efficient because it is comparing against `tab_p` once, vs the two times in the second query.

---

### Previously, both queries used SELECT *, no table alias in either of them.

No, those queries are not equivalent.

The first will return columns from both the derived table (UNION'd statement) and the `tab_p` table.  The second query will only return values from the derived table (UNION'd statement), and no columns from the `tab_p` table.  It's more obvious if you substitute the table aliases in the place of `SELECT *`:

### First query:

```
SELECT u.*, p.*
  FROM (SELECT a.a1    A,
               a.a2    B
          FROM tab_a a
        UNION ALL
        SELECT b.b1    A,
               b.b2    B
          FROM tab_b b) u,
       tab_p p
 WHERE p.a = u.a
```

### Second query:

```
SELECT x.*
 FROM (SELECT a.a1    A,
              a.a2    B
         FROM tab_a a,
              tab_p p
        WHERE p.a = a.a
       UNION ALL
       SELECT b.b1    A,
              b.b2    B
         FROM tab_b b,
              tab_p p
        WHERE p.a = b.a) x
```

There are no `tab_p` columns in the SELECT clause of the inner query, for the outer query to provide in the ultimate resultset.

This:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT a.a1    A,
               a.a2    B
          FROM tab_a a
        UNION ALL
        SELECT b.b1    A,
               b.b2    B
          FROM tab_b b) u
  JOIN tab_p p ON p.a = u.a
```

..is equivalent to the first query.  It's using ANSI-92 join syntax vs the ANSI-89 syntax used in the first query.

Comment: Ok, I've fixed this, now the first query selects only the union'd view. The question still remains.

Comment: @milan: That's not fair to us to change the details of the question.  We aren't notified about question changes, our answers risk being downvoted for not relating to the question.  I realize it seems trivial, but proper etiquette is to mark an answer for the existing question and create a new question.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: just my 2c: I agree it's not nice if someone changes their question, but in this case, has the question been changed or just their syntax corrected? Anyway, as an upvoter/downvoter I do look at the question edits to see whether a downvote is really warranted, or if the answer just needs editing. Also, you do have the option of deleting your answer if it is no longer relevant :) (I've done this on a few occasions, where the original question was changed as the questioner understood their requirements better, and updated their question accordingly)

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp: Sure, but you're *sane* :)

Comment: @OMG Ponies: tables tab_a and tab_b could be huge and have high selectivity on columns a1 and b1 respectively, while tab_p could be small. Join columns are, normally, indexed. Oracle RDMS knows this facts because it has statistics. But, yeah that's also something I should have mentioned in the question. Although, the question is *why it can't* merge the view.

Comment: @milan: Sorry, I haven't paid question titles too much attention to date.  I don't see why Oracle would use something similar to predicate push for this situation--joining on the result afterwards is a single scan of `tab_p` vs the two (or more depending on the query) for the example.  The optimizer algorithm is beyond me, though.

Comment: I the non-merged query, both huge tables have to be read in entirety.

Answer (score 0):

They are not equivalent. The second query will fail, as `u` is not defined.